# Custom VFS provider for Amazon S3 within WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

Is there a way to add a custom provider to VFS within WSO2 ESB? The requirement is to add a custom VFS provider for S3 within WSO2 ESB. I have tried it out with Apache Commons VFS on its own but can't figure out a way to customise WSO2 ESB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own vfs listener / sender classes (see repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml and search for transportReceiver name="vfs" and transportSender name="vfs").

You can add your own providers (see repository/components/plugins/commons-vfs2_2.0.0.wso2v14.jar : in META-INF/vfs-provider.xml you will have a sample that add a "smb" and a "mime" provider) and have a look to this sample : http://detailfocused.blogspot.fr/2009/06/add-plugin-for-apache-vfs.html

But probably the best way would be to use the dedicated esb connector for Amazon s3, see
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Amazon+S3+Connector